# Calculating TableViewCellHeight with Collectionview inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Yes, I know that there are a lot of questions in the `stackoverflow` about this problem. But My question is a little bit different so that `CollectionView` Cell Elements are `UILabels`. I can show `CollectionView` elements like below:

[image]

When I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, it dismiss `CollectionView` and not allow it to fire its `delegates`.

I want to use `heightForRowAt`, cannot calculate `UILabel` row count to detect total `CollectionView` content height. Because `UILabel` width is changeable, sometimes 2 or 3 labels can be side by side. I hope that I could have explained the problem.

I try something like below, but It does not work completely. Sometime `tableviewCell` covers `CollectionView`. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_PLACE_DETAILED_KEYWORDS_TABLE_VIEW) as? PlaceDetailedKeywordsTableViewCell {
            let keywords = self.placeInfo?.keywords
            let btnHeight:CGFloat = PreferencesCollectionConstants.keywordsBtnHeight
            let titleLabelHeight = cell.titleLabel.frame.height
            let spaceBetweenTitleAndCollection: CGFloat = 10

            var rows = Helper.calcRowsCountOfPrefsForTableCell(data: keywords!, contentInset: self.contentInset, cellSpace: self.minItemSpacing, collectionViewWidth: cell.collectionView.frame.width,prefBtnHeight:  btnHeight,font: font2)
            rows = ceil(rows)


            let tableViewCellHeight = titleLabelHeight + spaceBetweenTitleAndCollection + rows*keywordsBtnHeight
            return tableViewCellHeight  
        }

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: try to add like this: titleLabelHeight + spaceBetweenTitleAndCollection + yourCollectionView.contentSize.height

Comment: @Incredible_Dev in the heightForRowAt, collectionview.contentSize is 0. Because if tableviewcell height is not available, collectionview data is not filled. So Collectionview delegate requires ENOUGH tableview cell to start work.